# Best method of profiling Entity Framework 4 dynamic queries?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

What is the best method to profile dynamic queries that the entity framework generates?  I've been using Sql Server Profiler so far, but I was hoping that there's a better way in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Entity Framework Profiler](http://efprof.com/)

Comment: I didn't know Oren decided to develop a sibling to NHProfiler (one of my favorite tools for NHibernate).  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like the [Tracing Provider Wrapper](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers)?